# Hide/Delete chart from excel using epplus

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, epplus

I am using epplus to create excel with chart where I have added 2 column charts in excel sheet and we are using this excel sheet as template.

Now, If any of the chart doesnt have data then I want to hide/delete the chart from the sheet while downloading. But, I am unable to find such option.

Below is my code

```
ExcelDrawing excelDrawing = excelWorksheet.Drawings["Chart1"];
```

After this I am not getting any option in excelDrawing object to hide/show/delete OR else do I need to go in different way ?

Any help on this appreciated !

Comment: Can you check if you have something like `excelWorkSheet.Drawings.Remove(excelDrawing);`?

Comment: @ikerbera Hey thats working.. thanks for the help